# Infinite while loop using a quadrature

Tags: octave, numerical-integration

My code has a problem where if I use the condition of while n >= 1 it goes on forever, this happens because it never actually satisfies the if condition that breaks the loop.

This is the code itself:

```
#define x, y e T
x = @(t) t;
y = @(t) t*exp(-t/4);
T = (0:0.5:15);
#definir x' e y'
x_deriv = 1;
y_deriv = @(t) ((-(t-4)/4) * e^(t/4))^2;
#definir a e b
a = 0;
b = 15;

#Definir a função
F = @(z) (sqrt(x_deriv^2 + y_deriv(z)));

#Define os pesos segundo regra de simpson
A1 = (b-a)/6;
A2 = 2*(b-a)/3;
A3 = (b-a)/6;
#começa o contador

n = 1;
while n >= 1
  #fazer a quadratura mudando-a consoante n
  #break quando qn - q2n <= 10^-6
  h = (b-a)/n;
  i = 0;
  k = 0;
  valor_1_final = [];
  valor_2_final = [];
  valor_3_final = [];
  xk_final = [];
  while k <= n-1
    for l = 1:length(T)  
      xk = a + h*k;
      xi_1 = xk + (h*(1+0)/2);
      xi_2 = xk + h/2;
      xi_3 = xk + (h*(1+T(l))/2);
      valor_1 = F(xi_1);
      valor_2 = F(xi_2);
      valor_3 = F(xi_2);
      valor_1_final = [valor_1_final, valor_1];
      valor_2_final = [valor_2_final, valor_2];
      valor_3_final = [valor_3_final, valor_3];
      k = k + 1;
      xk_final = [xk_final, xk];
  
      sum1 = sum(valor_1_final);
      sum2 = sum(valor_2_final);
      sum3 = sum(valor_3_final);
      Qn = ((b-a)/2*n) * (A1*sum1 + A2*sum2 + A3*sum3);
      Q2n = ((b-a)/4*n) * (A1*sum1 + A2*sum2 + A3*sum3);
    endfor
  endwhile

  if abs(Qn - Q2n) <= 10e-6
    n_escolhido = n;
    break
  endif

  n = n + 1;
endwhile
disp(n_escolhido);
```

If I change the while statment so it is something of finite lenght it actually stops, everything works normally, execpt the if statement is never run, and as such the n_escolhido stays undefined.

Comment: `while n >= 1` is misleading, because that condition will never be false. You should write `while true` to indicate the loop ends with a `break` elsewhere.

Comment: I don’t know the algorithm you’re using, but I don’t immediately see why `Qn` and `Q2n` are expected to converge. You might want to revisit your equations. Please [edit] your post to describe what you’re computing and with what algorithm. “Quadrature” can mean many things…

Comment: What is the role of `T`, especially in the special formula for `xi_3 = xk + (h*(1+T(l))/2);`? `Qn` is the quadrature value for `n` segments, `Q2n` for `2*n` segments. These use different node sequences, the second is twice as dense as the first. One can re-use the previously computed function values by employing the relation of midpoint, trapezium and Simpson quadrature formulas. // It would force you into more clarity if you changed from this spaghetti code to more structured code, extracting functional blocks of code into separate functions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the descriptions of both [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave]. They are **not** the same, thus please only use both tags when asking about the similarities/differences between the two. Using both tags could result in answers being incompatible to the other software, unnecessarily forcing answerers to check validity of their code in both programs.

Answer (score 2):

The loop never ends because `Qn` is about `I*n^2` where `I` is the exact value of the integral, and `Q2n` is always `Qn/2`, so their difference never becomes small.

The first error could be repaired by replacing `((b-a)/2*n)` with `((b-a)/(2*n))`.

To get the correct value for `Q2n` you would have to repeat the computation with a refined subdivision. To avoid repeating code, make it a function `simpson(f,a,b,n)`.

In total, straight-forward and not optimized for efficiency, the main loop could look like

```
n=15;
do
  n *= 2;
  Qn = simpson(f,a,b,n);
  Q2n = simpson(f,a,b,2*n);
until abs(Qn-Q2n) < eps;
```

To avoid some redundant computations this can be changed to

```
n=15;
Q2n = simpson(f,a,b,2*n);
do
  n *= 2;
  Qn = Q2n;
  Q2n = simpson(f,a,b,2*n);
until abs(Qn-Q2n) < eps;
```

This form bounds the error estimate for `Qn` to be below `eps`. The last `Q2n` has an error smaller below `eps/16`. To have the last computed value to be the first inside this error bound, use `abs(Qn-Q2n) < 15*eps`.

---

The Simpson quadrature can be as short as

```
function S = simpson(f,a,b,n)
  x = linspace(a,b,2*n+1);
  S = f(a)+f(b);
  S += 2*sum( f(x(3:2:2*n-1)) );
  S += 4*sum( f(x(2:2:2*n)) )  
  S *= (b-a)/(6*n);
end%function
```

Comment: It why not keep the value from the previous iteration?

Comment: Yes, several improvements of that basic loop are possible. One could also update the current approximation using only the function values at the new points. This all is only useful if this routine will be frequently used so that it becomes a time-critical part of a larger project.

Answer (score -1):

**1.-** The outer `while` loop does not break because outside the loop you set `n=1`, then you tell the `while` loop to do things but `n` is **not brought down at any point inside the loop**, not a single time, anywhere inside this outer loop.

As posted, `k` is not `n`.

**2.-** Then you nest another `while` loop inside the 1st `while` loop where a single loop would be more efficient.

**3.- Replace** the outer `while` condition

```
while (n>=1)
```

with

```
while (abs(Qn - Q2n) <= 10e-6)
```

and remove the `if` clause inside the `while` loop.

**4.-** Also, it's highly probable that for the task at hand, it all can be solved with just 1 `for` loop, the one you nested inside the nested `while` loop.

Comment: The problem described by the OP is why the if condition (the one that contains a break) is never met

Comment: PierU I understand your comment but the question is about why while loop never exits. This is what is primarily asked. Then the question originator guessed that it may be because the only place where he thinks there's a chance to change something to exit is never done either : the if clause you mention. But even there in that if clause there's no modification of n therefore n remains 1 and therefore while keeps going on and on. Rewording ; the if clause doesn't matter, as it is, because n remains untouched.

Comment: I think the OP is expecting the if condition to be met at some point. If it is not, then something went wrong in the algorithm. The while loop is here only to set a maximum number of iterations, but for testing the OP has removed any iteration limit. That said the OP doesn't give enough details to be able to help him about the reason why the algorithm does not converge.

Comment: Moving the condition to a different place will not make the condition be met magically. The problem is elsewhere. Also, OP needs to break out of the loop when the condition is met (algorithm converges), your alteration reverses the logic, the algorithm only loops if the condition is met, which makes no sense.